# Unable to prepare ggplot statement dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to prepare ggplot statement dynamically by using below function. So that i can choose my Geom types (Geom_point(),Geom_jitter(),Geom_bar(),etc...) based on my data attributes from shiny web app. The problem here i am facing is "graph_type" where it's parsing as string with double quotes, due to that reason function not working properly. Is there any way i could remove double quotes from input value make selection dynamic ?.

```
    func_ggplt <-
  function(xAxis,
           yAxis,
           aes_color = NULL,
           graph_type,
           title = NULL,
           xAxis_label = NULL,
           yAxis_label = NULL) {
    p1 <- ggplot(ggplt_data, aes_string(xAxis, yAxis, color = aes_color))
    graph_type <- as.name(graph_type)
    p2 <- graph_type
    p3 <- geom_smooth()
    p4 <- ggtitle(title)
    p5 <- xlab(xAxis_label)
    p6 <- ylab(yAxis_label)
    p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6
    }
```

Below are the input values to function which i am trying.

```
func_ggplt('TCM.Deal.net.USD.M_dollar','TCM.Total.Quantity.M_dollar',NULL,"geom_point()",'MyTest','TCMUSD','TCMQTY')
```

Comment: If you pass `"geom_point"` (without parentheses), you can simply use `+ get(graph_type)()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but the simplest is by adding the geom_type to the argument call without apostrophes like this:

```r
ggtest <- function(test) {
  geom_type = eval(parse(text = test))
  summarized_df %>% ggplot(aes(n, n_image)) + geom_type
}

ggtest("geom_point()")
```

Comment: thank you Fnguyen for you quick reply, in my case if passing those value through shiny input, so the values are passing with in double quotes.

Comment: Please do not recommend `eval(parse())`. That's always a bad solution and never necessary (see my comment above).

Comment: Thanks Roland, Fnguyen. Both solutions are working, i will use "get" function for my solution.